# How to use the slide navigation UI pattern with listview?

Tags: android

I'm using the new [slide navigation UI pattern](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html) in my android app, yet it keeps crashing when I use it with a vertical listview. The listview listener on my main screen conflicts with the slide menu listener, which causes the crash when they both capture the motion events.

I know using two different listeners for motion events isn't recommended, yet many applications use it nowadays (like Youtube and Facebook). How did they manage to do it? Any useful libraries out there that can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement list view on the main screen, you would do that using any of the ListViewAdapter. For implementing listView on the side screen when the view is slided you need to implement using ListFragment.

Also, you may refer example in https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu